# How the feedback circuitry of a Tesla Coil works?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, tesla-coil

I have a project to do in school which is a DIY musical Telsa Coil and I need to build the hardware. I searched on the Internet and found these 2 schematics:

[image: tesla coil driver with an antenna]

[image: tesla coil driver with a current transformer]

My schematic is completely different from these two because it fulfils a different purpose, but the feedback circuitry is more or less the same. So my questions are:

1. How do these feedback circuits actually works?
2. How to choose which one to implement and what are the advantages and disadvantages of both?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see the feedback mechanism in the first circuit.

Comment: the feedback is via an antenna. Not something that I would've considered, but there's a few examples on the interwebs. It relies on the electrostatic field from the high voltage generated. My exposure to Tesla coils was neon transformers, and wound coils, hand made capacitors and spark gaps. Just how Telsa would've done it. No semiconductor garbage!

Comment: "My schematic is completely different from these two because it fulfils a different purpose, but the feedback circuitry is more or less the same. How do these feedback circuits actually works?" That's a funny situation. You have different device with the same feedback, but you don't know how it works.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič if youre not going to answer the question and be useful why are you typing?? I meant that its still a Tesla coil but its for a specific purpose. Which wasnt the point of the question.

Comment: You won't find the answer, because it's not clear what you are asking. Those two feedback are not the same, one uses the secondary electric field (voltage) to drive a resonant circuit while the other uses the secondary current. So which type is yours? You can't mix them, OK - the whole working principle differs.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I'm asking how do these work and what are the advantages and disadvantages of both. I don't want to mix them by any means. I just want to understand their working principles. I hope its clear now.